# What’s the limit we have seen of Hulk's strength?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk

I understand that the Incredible Hulk's strength is next to infinite, fueled by his anger; but what’s some of the greatest applications of this that we’ve seen? Either from the movies or the comics. At this point the greatest thing I have seen him do was when he one-punched the giant worm carrier in the first Avengers movie. Is there a larger application of his strength somewhere though, something more impressive? Examples are appreciated

Comment: @Vanguard3000 I’d go on a limb and say this isn’t fully a duplicate. It’s hard to say though. It really depends on how the author meant it. If you are planning on marking it I’d suggest asking the author of this question the meaning meant behind it.

Comment: @K.Lanie agreed, I want to know to what greatest extent he has currently ever used his powers

Comment: Ok if I where you I’d rewrite your question so it’s a duplicate anymore then copy it and delete this one and resubmit your revised question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hulk's strength varies with his anger. The more infuriated he gets, the stronger he gets also.

During the Secret Wars, Hulk held a mountain on his back:

[image: Holding a mountain]

That's 150,000,000,000,000 kilograms. Should be more than most other characters of his size could bear. But this is just a bad hair day anger for him. During the Planet Hulk series, the main antagonist used a device that caused the planet Sakaar to break apart. Massive rifts appear in the surface of the planet as it starts to break. So Hulk jumped onto bedrock and magma and held the two halves of the planet together.

[image: Holding tectonic plates together]

Even if we suppose that Sakaar has the same mass as Earth, I don't know how to calculate the forces involved in this particular scenario (and this is the kind of exercise that I am used to participate in, in the worldbuilding stack). But just as a mental exercise, if he can do that, he could probably do the opposite and pull two halves of an Earth-sized planet apart, if sufficiently angered. That would mean he could hold approximately 6x10<sup>24</sup> kilograms on his back.

Let me rewrite that without scientific notation:

That would mean he could hold approximately 6,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 kilograms on his back. You could also say six septillion kilograms (or six sixtillion tons), or a thousand yottagrams.

Comment: In that Secret Wars issue, he did not hold a mountain on his back.  In the dialog he mentions that he is only able to hollow out a space for the heroes to crouch in.  The cover is not very accurate.

Answer (score 1):

In the films at least I can say he can lift almost anything. But there seems to be only a single object that I can think of that he can’t lift which was Thor’s hammer. But when in his rampage state he can lift up too 100 tons but if he remains calm as the Hulk then he can only lift 70 tons according to [hulk dictionary](http://www.marveldirectory.com/individuals/h/hulk.htm).